# Getting 403 (Forbidden) deploy other then 80 port in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

Environment Details:

- ASP.net Core 2.2 web application
- IIS-7 (Deployment)

Error Details:
Getting 403 (Forbidden) while deploy application in IIS other then the 80 port (8080 , 8081).
 when deploy in port 80 API's are working fine. Same code & environment if i change the port  other the 80 is not working.

Comment: Do you have permissions to access a site hosted on port 8081 or 8080?

Comment: What kind of 403? Check the substatus code, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to check your firewall option to make sure you have enable the other port. Besides, I suggest you could try to use netsh -a to check the 90 or other port is starting to listen the http request.